# 3 Dimensional Complex Plane?

Tags: complex-numbers

We all know, that all real numbers are complex numbers also. But in real numbers, there are multi-dimensional coordinate planes. Is there such thing in complex numbers also? If yes, what is there meaning and how do we represent numbers over there? 
**Edit**: Things are getting clearer now. But my question slightly changes, 
***1. Are multidimensional complex planes used in real? What is there use? If no, why not?*** 
***2. Please give an example of a "line" in a 3D complex plane. And what is the meaning of coordinates in a multidimensional complex plane?***

Comment: Perhaps use co-ordinates like $(z_1,z_2,z_3$) where each $z_i$ can be a complex number

Comment: But what would be there meaning? Complex numbers cant be compared.

Comment: You can answer questions like "How far apart are two points?" and "Do three points lie on a straight line?"

Comment: Is it used in real?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complex plane is a two dimensional real vector space (using the natural identification $(x,y)=x+iy$). Of course one can form the (complex) vector spaces $\mathbb C^n$ for each positive integer $n$, that is, a complex space of dimension $n$; the set of all $(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ for $z_j\in\mathbb C$. However$,$ since $\mathbb C$ is identified with $\mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb C^{n}$ is identified with $\mathbb R^{2n}$ in the same natural way.

When discussing dimensions, you need to specify what field you are considering (the real numbers, complex numbers, rational numbers, etc).

Comment: How is $\mathbb{C}$ identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: And what does "identified" mean here?

Comment: Using the map $(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$. And in this context, identified means that there is a bijective linear map from $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb C$ (in terms of vector spaces, this is equivalence). One can also show that the map, as above, has many other "structure preserving" properties.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I don't seem to understand what maps are? Linear maps?

Comment: A map (function) is a relation which relates a point with another point, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics). A linear map $f$ is a function which preserves the structure of a vector space, like the spaces discussed in my answer.